# Where's the Azure SDK version 2.9?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net, web-platform-installer

In late March Microsoft [announced the release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/) of the Azure SDK version 2.9.

On that page, as well as from within Visual Studio 2015, I'm invited to download and install it.

If I do so, the Web Platform Installer (5.0) fires up and shows me this:

[image]

That's strange...I don't want version 2.8.2...I already have it.

So I click the "back" button in Web Platform Installer and try to find 2.9 manually. At the time of writing, I'm seeing this:

[image]

That is, in the Web Platform Installer's list of products, version 2.9 is not there.

I'm on Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2015 (with the latest update 2). My Web Platform Installer is version 5 and its primary feed is set as "default". Normally I have no problems installing an updated Azure SDK in this way.

I tried deleting the installer cache in Web Platform Installer (no help).

Can anybody give me a hint as to what might be happening here? Is anybody able to reproduce it (not finding v2.9 in the products list on WPI) on their machines? Could it be possible that v2.9 has been accidentally removed from the MS servers...any way to check this directly at the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason it is not shown in the Web installer. This are the steps to fix it:

1 run a reset on the installer:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\WebPlatformInstaller.exe" /reset
```

2 run the following registry fix:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebPlatformInstaller]
"Install"=dword:00000001
"ProductXMLLocation"="http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue. See the comments on this page:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/

Answer (score 0):

Please search "2.9" in Web Platform Installer search pane. You will be able to see "Microsoft Azure SDK for .Net (VS2013)-2.9.6" in searched results.