# Solution Please- need update from Azure SDK 2.7 to 2.9

Tags: azure

I need to update from Azure SDK 2.7 to 2.9 to publish to azure web app
web platform installer can not install azure sdk 2.9. it give me the following
"Microsoft web platform installer couldn't find the product you tried to install "
I used VS community 2015 - update 3
I need that update to publish my project to azure web app. where without that update i can not preview my existing web app in vs publish dialogue box.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where's the Azure SDK version 2.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664658/wheres-the-azure-sdk-version-2-9)

Answer (score 0):

now I don't need the update
because I deployed on Azure web app using profile from azure
steps:
1- create web app on Azure portal
2- create profile from this web app - the profile will save inside your computer
3- open visual studio and right click on the website name then select publish
4- select profile from the left pane
5- select import from "Select a publish target" part
6- select the saved profile
7- finally press publish
and enjoy your website as web app on azure